# Ignore Folder Inside Folders

Tags: dart, kiln

I am trying to ignore all the packages folders generated by dart in my solution

I am trying to use this ignore line but it is not ignoring the folders. What am i doing wrong?

```
Src/LiveScoringDart/LiveScoring/**/packages/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think just  `packages/` should do

As far as I have read this is Regexp.
You could try

> Src/LiveScoringDart/LiveScoring/.+?/packages/

Comment: but i only want to ignore packages folders inside that folder

Comment: yeah but i also have nuget packages and that will ignore them aswell